# python column major and row major matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

how do i get the 1-D index of an element of a matrix?

for example:

```
b=np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
c = b.reshape(2,3,order='F')#colmaj
d = b.reshape(2,3)#rowmaj
```

this is c:

```
([[1, 3, 5],
 [2, 4, 6]])
```

this is d:

```
([[1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6]])
```

if i do c[1,2] i get the element 6, and i need to get the index of the 1-D array which would be 5.  i can do this mentally but if i have a large matrix and need to select an element at random i won't be able to. i need to write functions to do this for both colmajor and rowmajor matrices.

```
def linearize_colmajor(i, j, m, n):        
        """
        Returns the linear index for the `(i, j)` entry of
        an `m`-by-`n` matrix stored in column-major order.
        """
```

Comment: `np.ravel_multi_index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply scale the row index by the number of columns and add column index for the row-major order. For the col-major order, use number of rows to scale the row-index and add column index again.

Hence, to get the flattened index for `rowmaj` version -

```
i*n+j
```

To get the flattened index for `colmaj` version -

```
i+m*j
```

where :

```
i = row index
j = col index
m = number of rows in the matrix
n = number of columns in the matrix
```

Putting into function format -

```
def linearize(i, j, m, n, order='C'):
    if order=='C': # rowmaj
        return i*n+j
    elif order=='F': # colmaj
        return i+m*j
    else:
        raise Exception("Invalid order value")
```

Sample run -

```
In [42]: linearize(i=1, j=1, m=2, n=3, order='C')
Out[42]: 4 # element : 5 in rowmaj array, d

In [43]: linearize(i=1, j=1, m=2, n=3, order='F')
Out[43]: 3 # element : 4 in colmaj array, c
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.ravel_multi_index` converts n-d index to a flat one, with the option of specifying `order`:

```
In [152]: np.ravel_multi_index((0,2),(2,3),order='C')                           
Out[152]: 2
In [153]: c[0,2], c.flat[2]                                                     
Out[153]: (5, 5)
```

Application to the `order='F'` case is a bit trickier:

```
In [154]: np.ravel_multi_index([0,2],[2,3],order='F')                           
Out[154]: 4
In [155]: d[0,2], d.flat[4], d.ravel(order='F')[4]                              
Out[155]: (3, 5, 3)
In [156]: d.ravel()                                                             
Out[156]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
In [157]: d.ravel(order='F')                                                    
Out[157]: array([1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6])
```

The `[1,2]` element is the same in both orders, the last '6'.

Comparison with @Divakar's example:

```
In [160]: np.ravel_multi_index([1,1],[2,3],order='C')                           
Out[160]: 4
In [161]: np.ravel_multi_index([1,1],[2,3],order='F')                           
Out[161]: 3
```